# Как реализовать автоматическое определение оптимального пути на карте между точками?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Возникла проблема с Yandex Map. я реализую построение маршрута между выбранными точками

```
this.multiRoute = new window.ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    // Описание опорных точек мультимаршрута.
    referencePoints: [
     [55.734876, 37.59308],
     "Санкт-Петербург, Владимирский пр",
     "Москва, ул. Мясницкая"
    ],
    // Параметры маршрутизации.
    params: {
      // Ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором.
      results: 1
    }
  }, {
    // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
    boundsAutoApply: true
  });
```

Но не могу найти решение проблемы моей. Между точками указаны мною. Строится что я еду сначала в СПБ, потом только в МСК. 
Есть возможность, что бы Yandex Map определял сам оптимальный путь?
Спасибо за помощь :) Все добра и приятного кода :)

Answer (score 1):

JS API не решает за вас, куда вам ехать, т.к. это сервис скорее для визуализации заданного маршрута, где разработчик подумал сам, какие точки должны быть и в каком порядке.

Для решения логистических задач есть несколько API у платформы [Яндекс.Маршрутизация](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/?from=SO).